# Where could a paper on a unification of matrix decompositions be published?

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, sp.spectral-theory, modules, journals

I've got a paper which shows that when the spectral theorem (as a statement that every self-adjoint matrix can be unitarily diagonalised) is naively generalised to $*$-algebras other than the complex numbers, matrix decompositions like SVD, Takagi, skew-Takagi (and analogues of these over the quaternions) all get unified. In particular, a pair consisting of a left singular vector and a right singular vector behaves like an eigenvector in its own right.

The idea uses change-of-rings quite heavily. *Ring extension* is used to unify matrix decomposition, and *ring restriction* is used to pass from non-commutative to commutative rings, to ease calculations.

Is there a place where this would be of interest, and is publishable? There's a chance that this question is not appropriate here.

Comment: Have you considered journals specializing in linear algebra? "Linear Algebra and its Applications", for example.